# Check new messages in inbox

Tags: api, asana

I need to develop a watcher to verify new tasks in inbox and alert the user with a message in the desktop. I checked the documentation but I found nothing about.

Is there a way easier than taking all tasks and check the parameter assignee_status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't currently expose the inbox in the API, nor is there a way to get changes on tasks directly. However, we're currently working on a Change API that would allow you to subscribe to resources and listen to changes - it's too early to share the details, but I'll keep this answer updated when it changes.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this function by making a check on the last modified date of a task, and validating the story. Not ideal, but I believe it will work, I hope. xD
Meanwhile I await the implementation of the API